# Console warning presenting a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

```
@IBAction func signinButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

        let id   = usernameTextField.text;
        let pwd  = passwordTextField.text;

        if (id!.isEmpty || (pwd!.isEmpty)){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information!", message: "Username and Password is not empety", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

this error :
Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

please help me..

Comment: The very first thing to do in such a situation is to Google the error message. Have you done that and tried the advice given there? There's lots out there.

Comment: You have present statement twice which causes alert to be presented twice infact even before first one is completed hence the issue

Comment: Duplicate of the `present` line.

Comment: Couple of advice : 1. self.ActivityIndicator naming the variable in Title casing not a great idea should be using Camel Casing I mean it should be self.activityIndicator,    2. Its a warning thats printed on console not error

Comment: Try debugging the code. It will help you find the problem faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (just remove the last `self.present` line):

```
@IBAction func signinButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.ActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

        let id   = usernameTextField.text;
        let pwd  = passwordTextField.text;

        if (id!.isEmpty || (pwd!.isEmpty)){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information!", message: "Username and Password is not empety", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: This did not work.
when I want to press a button to log in, username and password are not in the content. should display the error message, but it does not display an error. direct entry menu.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. Using this code an alert should be shown **if id is empty OR if pwd is empty**. Try putting a breakpoint in on the `let alert ...` line and see if it's entering your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `present` functions. So just change your code from:

```
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to:

```
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

how to make a notification badge.
if there is new data when reloading at the table then displays the notification badge on tableview like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trWzc.png)